# Escape dollar sign in command line arguments

Tags: java, args

When I pass in "$1000" through the command line and retrieve the string through args[0], it becomes "000". How can I maintain the full string in my java code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you're using some kind of Unix system, as '$' is the variable symbol in bash & co. Try using single quotes (e.g. `java MyClass '$1000'`)

Comment: Is there any way programmatically to retain the full input in case double quotes are used?

Comment: No. Variable interpolation (the action of replacing a variable specified as `$FOO` by its value "BAR" or, in this case `$1` by the empty string)  is done by the shell before your program gets a hold of the data. You have absolutely no way of stopping it. The user *must* escape the data by `java MyClass '$1000'` or `java MyClass \$1000`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.